# Retaining highlighted text in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to remove the non highlighted region (turn it white) from this image and just retain the highlighted portions.
This is my image : [image: Input Image]

### Getting Highlighted Region

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread('0002.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

lower_green = (30, 90, 90)
upper_green = (100, 255, 255)

green_mask = cv2.inRange(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV), lower_green, upper_green)

_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

binary = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

preserved_highlights = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=binary)

image[green_mask == 0] = [255, 255, 255]
#cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', image) 

result = cv2.add(preserved_highlights, image)

cv2.imwrite('final.jpg', result)
```

### OUTPUT1

[image: Output]

### Increasing Clarity

As you can see the output is quite blurry, after applying some other operations :

```
image = cv2.imread('final.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

alpha = 1.5  
beta = 0 
enhanced = cv2.convertScaleAbs(gray, alpha=alpha, beta=beta)

sharpening_filter = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                              [-1, 9, -1],
                              [-1, -1, -1]])
sharpened = cv2.filter2D(enhanced, -1, sharpening_filter)

# Save the final result
cv2.imwrite('output_enhanced02.jpg', sharpened)
```

The best I could get was

#### FINAL OUTPUT

[image: Final Output]

## Question

Is there a way I can retain just the highlighted part like it is originally and just remove the non highlighted part?

OR if that's not possible

How can make my output look more readable and clear ?

Thank you

Comment: the text itself isn't actually highlighted. it's still black. the blank space around it is highlighted. does that give you ideas?

Comment: what is the *goal* of all this? half the page is markered. that's excessive by any reasonable standards. you're gonna apply OCR, aren't you...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have not yet decided, I was trying to make handwritten notes out of the content but most of it was important as you rightly pointed, So I wanted to try highlighting what was important and removing the rest.  Maybe I'll look into OCR but has been quite some time since I've coded, picked this up out of interest.  Thank you and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your code a little bit according to Christoph Rackwitz's comment.
Here is the result

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

image = cv.imread('Q0aCT.jpg', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)



lower_green = (0, 100, 0)
upper_green = (200, 255, 200)

green_mask = cv.inRange(image, lower_green, upper_green)


kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
openning = cv.morphologyEx(green_mask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)

kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8)
closing = cv.dilate(openning, kernel, iterations=3)


preserved_highlights = cv.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=closing)


gray = cv.cvtColor(preserved_highlights, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, preserved_text = cv.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
preserved_text = cv.bitwise_and(preserved_text, preserved_text, mask=closing)

cv.imwrite('final.png', 255 - preserved_text)
```

Steps to get the result

1. Using `cv.inRange` to find highlighted text
2. Use opening morphology to remove salt noise
3. Use close morphology to fill the black text inside the highlighted area
4. Use a binary threshold to extract those black areas

#### Final Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! I learnt a lot understanding through lines of code.

Comment: You're so welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code, takes input of a pdf, Thank you @Odeaxcsh

```html
python main.py input.pdf
```

```html
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import fitz 
from PIL import Image
import os
import img2pdf
import argparse

def process_image(image):

    lower_green = (0, 100, 0)
    upper_green = (200, 255, 200)

    green_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_green, upper_green)

    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    openning = cv2.morphologyEx(green_mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    kernel = np.ones((9, 9), np.uint8)
    closing = cv2.dilate(openning, kernel, iterations=3)


    preserved_highlights = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=closing)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(preserved_highlights, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    _, preserved_text = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    preserved_text = cv2.bitwise_and(preserved_text, preserved_text, mask=closing)

    return 255 - preserved_text



def main(input_pdf):
    output_dir = os.path.splitext(input_pdf)[0] + '/'
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

    pdf_document = fitz.open(input_pdf)
    processed_image_paths = []

    for page_number in range(pdf_document.page_count):
        page = pdf_document.load_page(page_number)
        image_list = page.get_pixmap(matrix=fitz.Matrix(300 / 72, 300 / 72))
        image = Image.frombytes("RGB", [image_list.width, image_list.height], image_list.samples)
        image_np = np.array(image)
        processed_image = process_image(image_np)

        image_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'page_{page_number + 1}.jpg')
        cv2.imwrite(image_path, processed_image)
        processed_image_paths.append(image_path)

    pdf_document.close()

    output_pdf = os.path.join(output_dir, 'output.pdf')
    with open(output_pdf, "wb") as pdf_output:
        pdf_output.write(img2pdf.convert(processed_image_paths))

    print(f'saved in "{output_dir}"')
    print(f'PDF saved - "{output_pdf}".')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process a PDF and save the result as a new PDF.")
    parser.add_argument("input_pdf", help="Input PDF file to process")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.input_pdf)
```